# Converting a string representation of an array into an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a string in Java like this:

```
String s = "{{\"2D\", \"array\"}, {\"represented\", \"in a string\"}}"
```

How can I convert it into an actual array? Like so:

```
String[][] a = {{"2D", "array"}, {"represented", "in a string"}}
```

(What I'm looking for is a solution a bit like python's `eval()`)

Comment: Maybe you could regard it as a JSON input. Take a look at this http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ Maybe there's a way to parse string objects.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: It's not in JSON format, arrays in JSON use `[...]`, not `{...}`. If it's *really* as simple as shown, of course the OP could do a `replaceAll` first to change those over, but it's probably not actually as simple as shown.

Comment: The real question is, what situation are you running into that requires you to do this?

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far that isn't working? I'm surprised a question that shows no research effort at all is getting so many up-votes.

Comment: Your example makes no sense. You declare a `String[]` and initialize it with `String[][]`. If you don't know in advance the dimensionality of your array, this is not a simple problem at all.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: So it's always two-dimensional?

Comment: @agarhy I was clever enough to build a program that works of `String[][]`s. Only after completing the example program did I realise that when I get the real data I will be using it won't come in that format. Rather than rebuild the entire program, I thought Java might have an equivilent of python's `eval()`

Comment: No such luck, Java is not an interpreted language like Python. There are solutions, but they are extremely complex and not worth for your use case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik alright, It sounds like I should go for JSON and change the array methods. thanks.

Comment: ... I agree. Where and how are you getting the data? It might be easier for the program that is the source of the data to output it to you in a format you can easily read, instead of you attempting to read it in a difficult format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you use a json capable library to parse your `String`. However, just for fun, please take a look at the code below, that does the thing you need using only `String` methods:

```
String s = "{{\"2D\", \"array\"}, {\"represented\", \"in a string\"}}";
s = s.replace("{", "");
String[] s0 = s.split("},\\s");
int length = s0.length;
String[][] a = new String[length][];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    a[i] = s0[i].replace("}", "").split(",\\s");
}
```

Comment: Where this will fail is any `{` or `}` occuring in the strings.